# Similar Binary Trees

Tags: c++

I have written the following function to check of two b-trees are similar or not. But I am not getting the desired output.

```
int bt_similar(btree *b1, btree *b2)
{
    int m=1;
    if ((b1->data==b2->data&&(((b1->lchild==NULL&&b2->lchild==NULL)||(b1->lchild!=NULL&&b2->lchild!=NULL))&&((b1->rchild==NULL&&b2->rchild==NULL)||(b1->rchild!=NULL&&b2->rchild!=NULL))))&&(m))
    {
        if (b1->lchild!=NULL)
        m=bt_similar(b1->lchild,b2->lchild);
        if (b1->rchild!=NULL)
        m=bt_similar(b1->rchild,b2->rchild);
        if (m)
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a little confusing saying Binary Tree in title and b-tree (which usually is used to mean a Balanced Tree) in the question.

Comment: I assume you're not referring to a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: Its a loooong if statement, but it looks like you are checking if the data of b1 and b2 are the same and if the children both contain somthing or both contain nothing for either side...? You don't need the "&& (m)" at the end since you have just assigned it to "=1" the line before :)  ... what is the issue then? - always returns 0;?. I recommend expanding the long "if" statement into a few nested if's so that you can debug it and make it more readable (then reconstruct later if you wish)

Comment: Your code is trying to compare two trees as *identical* (and frankly, in a *very* difficult-to-read code-block); not *similar*. As you know, binary trees can have different parent-child representations and yet still produce the same sorted order from an inorder traversal. Is your choice of wording accurate? Do you want to compare them for *similarity* or do you want to see if they are *identical* ?

Comment: You tagged this as C++, not C, so why are you using `int` to represent a boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you could benefit a lot from breaking up your code, in particular that big condition in the `if` statement on the fourth line is *nasty*. Why not just handle the null case in the method itself? eg:

```
if (b1 == null && b2 != null)
    return 0;
if (b2 == null && b1 != null)
    return 0;
if (b1 == null && b2 == null)
    return 1;
```

As far as I can tell, the actual problem with your code is where you overwrite the value of m at line 9, without taking the previous value into consideration. If the left-hand-side of the tree is not similar but the right is, the return will be 1. Instead of:

```
    if (b1->lchild!=NULL)
    m=bt_similar(b1->lchild,b2->lchild);
    if (b1->rchild!=NULL)
    m=bt_similar(b1->rchild,b2->rchild);
```

You should have:

```
    if (b1->lchild!=NULL)
        m = bt_similar(b1->lchild,b2->lchild);
    if (b1->rchild!=NULL)
        m = m && bt_similar(b1->rchild,b2->rchild);
```

Comment: Or `if (b1 == null) return (b2 == null); else if (b2 == null) return 0;`, but I suppose writing it out has its advantages.

Comment: Or `if (b1 == null || b2 == null) return b1 == b2`.

Comment: Well, arguably the best is: `if (b1 == b2) return true; if (b1 == NULL || b2 == NULL) return false;` - as this also optimises the comparison in case the tree is being compared with itself. I personally find this more comprehensible than the two suggestions above, also, but it does come down to personal taste I guess.

Answer (score 1):

you should make sure that if b1 == NULL or b2 == NULL...

```
bool compare(struct node* b1, struct node* b2) {

    // 1. both empty -> true
    if (b1==NULL && b2==NULL) return(true);   

    // 2. both non-empty -> compare them
    else if (b1!=NULL && b2!=NULL) {
        return(
            b1->data == b2->data &&
            compare(b1->lchild, b2->lchild) &&
            compare(b1->rchild, b2->rchild));
    }

    // 3. one empty, one not -> false
    else return false;
}
```

and, [b-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is not short for [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).